# Error during Insert JSON object in variant data type -snowflake stored procedure

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm facing an error when inserting a JSON object into a `VARIANT` data type column, from within a stored procedure in Snowflake.

Below is the reference code:

```sql
create or replace procedure test1234()
returns varchar not null
language javascript
as
$$
       var birthDateVar = 'BIRTH_DATE'; 
       var genderVar = 'GENDER';
       var countryVar = 'COUNTRY';
       var loanVar = 'LOAN_AMOUNT'; 
       var emailVar = 'EMAIL';
       var tableName = 'SF_STRUCT_STAGE_RAW';
       var UPDATE_DATE = "2019-01-01"; 
       var email = "XXX@gmail.com";
       var row_num = "1";
       var person_id = "1";
       var EMAILERROR = {
        "row_num": row_num,
        "person_id": person_id,  
        "tableName": tableName,
        "fieldName": emailVar,
        "fieldValue": email,
        "errorDesc":  'value is invalid email'
       };

       var cmd = "insert into error_details_log values(:1,:2);";
       var stmt = snowflake.createStatement(
        {
            sqlText: cmd,
            binds: [EMAILERROR, UPDATE_DATE]
        }
        );
       stmt.execute();
       return emailError;
$$;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inserting `Object` types via binding variables directly is *not currently supported* from within Stored Procedures. Quoting the relevant portion [from the Snowflake documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-usage.html#binding-variables):

> When you bind JavaScript variables to SQL statements, Snowflake converts from the JavaScript data types to the SQL data types. **You can bind variables of the following JavaScript data types**:
>
> - number
> - string
> - SfDate

However, [the example in the documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-usage.html#binding-variables) for `TIMESTAMP` datatypes involving use of strings and recasting can be adapted for your use-case, using the [`PARSE_JSON(…)`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/parse_json.html) function and [`JSON.stringify(…)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) JavaScript API:

```js
[…]
// Convert Object -> String
var EMAILERROR_str = JSON.stringify(EMAILERROR);

// Ask Snowflake to parse String as JSON (String -> Object)
var cmd = "insert into error_details_log select PARSE_JSON(:1), :2;";

var stmt = snowflake.createStatement(
  {
    sqlText: cmd,

    // Bind the String value, not the Object one
    binds: [EMAILERROR_str, UPDATE_DATE]

  }
);
[…]
```

Comment: Thanks Harsh, i tried using parse_json earlier but forgot to convert into string , so wasn't working .